# Vue.js How to use <template v-slot> on Props

Tags: vue.js, vue-props, v-slot

thanks for reading my question. I've a dynamic table and I'm trying to use a prop in v-slot, like bellow:

```
      <v-data-table :headers="chooseHeader" :items="chooseItem" :search="search">
        <template v-slot:[`item.iconValue`]>
          <v-icon> mdi-clipboard-edit-outline </v-icon>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>

<script>   
export default {
  name: 'EasyHrPerformanceEvaluationListsNewSolicitation',

  props: {
    iconValue: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
    },
    chooseHeader: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    chooseItem: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
```

I call the component EasyHrPerformanceEvaluationListsNewSolicitation to pass the prop values:

```
<EasyHrPerformanceEvaluationListsNewSolicitation
                    :title="$t('Novas Avaliações')"
                    :chooseHeader="selfEvaluationsHeader"
                    :chooseItem="selfEvaluations"
                    :iconValue="makeEvaluation" //v-slot value
                  >
</EasyHrPerformanceEvaluationListsNewSolicitation>
```

Bellow is my page, if you have a look you can se the column  "avaliar" isn't working (my v-slot)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EWrb.png)

Is possible to use the prop value bellow in my v-slot?

```
iconValue: {
          type: Object,
          required: false,
        },
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Kindly explain more on how your code works and what does `chooseHeader` and `chooseItem` looks like. Also what is the reason behind using `iconValue` as a prop.

Comment: Although whatever I have understood from your code. I have answered it below. In case if it not works. Do explain your code as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

I think from the syntax you are using vuetify data table. And as per the doc's, slots are to be written like this.

```
<template v-slot:[`item.iconValue`]="{item}">
```

Refer -> https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#item